# warning : function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) ''

Tags: javascript

```
for (let i = 0; i < state.columns.length; i++) {
  var column = state.columns[i];
  var sortIndex;
  var fsColumn = firstSortColumns.find((v, i) => {
    sortIndex = i;
    return v.dataField === column.dataField;
  });
  if (fsColumn) {
    //...
  } else {
    //...
  }
}
```

Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) 'sortIndex', 'column'.

I am getting a warning like this, how can i fix this?

Comment: I would suggest using `.findIndex()` instead of `.find()`, and then using the index you get back to get `fsColumn`

Comment: `(v, i) => ...` creates a new variable `i` with the same name as the loop variable. You could be a bit more imaginitive and use a different variable name. perhaps you could use `j` instead!

Comment: @phuzi Well, the `i` overshadows the other `i`, but that won’t lead to problems.

Comment: No, but it's what the linter is complaining about. I understand the scope is different but somebody who is new to JS might confuse the two.

Comment: I would urge you to avoid `var` completely. Always use `const`. If you can’t use `const`, use `let`.

Comment: @phuzi The linter doesn’t complain about `i`; it complains about `column` and `sortIndex`, because they’re not scoped to the iteration but to the surrounding function (or global scope).

Comment: I used let instead of var, it worked! thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your linter is being overly cautious here. Since the function you pass to `find` isn't called asynchronously, the fact the value of  `column` can change isn't a problem.

If it were async then you could solve the problem by using `let` instead of `var` since it has block-scope instead of function-scope (and doing so would shut up your linter).

Answer (score 1):

> Declare variables outside of the iteration (loop) and modify inside the for loop.

```
var column, fsColumn, sortIndex;
for (let i = 0; i < state.columns.length; i++) {
   column = state.columns[i];
   sortIndex;
   fsColumn = firstSortColumns.find((v, i) => {
    sortIndex = i;
    return v.dataField === column.dataField;
  });
  if (fsColumn) {
    //...
  } else {
    //...
  }
}
```